# Python Flask, display an image stored as a binary blob in MySQL database

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to display an image that is stored in a `LONGBLOB` column in a `MySQL` database, using Flask:

**app.py**:

```
@app.route('/get_image', methods=['GET'])
def get_image():
    args = request.args
    image_id = args.get('image_id')

    image = # code for getting image blob from database
    return send_file(image, mimetype='image/png')
```

**HTML code**:

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_image?image_id=1"/>
```

When a request for the image is sent, I can see in debugger that the image bytes are retrieved from the database:

[image]

However the image is not displayed:

[image]

Comment: Is `image` here bytes, or a "file like object"? What if you try `send_file(io.BytesIO(image), mimetype='image/png')`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! What was the problem? My `image` was a byte array, but should have been an object?

Comment: Yes, that sums it up :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `send_file` function expects a path-like or file-like object, not a `bytes` object. Use `BytesIO` to give your `bytes` a file-like interface:

```py
from io import BytesIO

@app.route('/get_image', methods=['GET'])
def get_image():
    args = request.args
    image_id = args.get('image_id')

    image = # code for getting image blob from database

    #                   
    return send_file(BytesIO(image), mimetype='image/png')
```